# Apply foreach to multiple arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I've been playing around with this one for a few days, I'm not a professional coder but I'm trying to put a nice basic system in place to manage checkin/out at a local volunteer rescue organization.

Basically I'm trying to get all members member with the `ISLOGGEDIN` value set as `1`

```
$loggedin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE ISLOGGEDIN=1");
$loggedinarray=mysql_fetch_array($loggedin);
```

And present their information (name, etc) into a table:

```
foreach($loggedinarray as $key=>$value) {
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$value[firstname]." ".$value[lastname]."</td>
        <td>".$value[timeloggedin]."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
```

However the results I'm getting are quite random and not what I'm looking for, at all!

`var_dump($loggedinarray)` output:

```
array(12) { [0]=> string(5) "5395" ["SES_ID"]=> string(5) "5395" [1]=> string(7) "Anthony" ["FIRST"]=> string(7) "Anthony" [2]=> string(8) "LastName" ["LAST"]=> string(8) "Willison" [3]=> string(1) "1" ["ISLOGGEDIN"]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "0" ["TRAINER"]=> string(1) "0" [5]=> string(1) "1" ["OFFICER"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _“the results I'm getting are quite random and not what I'm looking for, at all!”_ – well then what _are_ you looking for …?

Comment: var_dump($loggedinarray); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `while`; it was random, because it fetched only one row from table.

```
$loggedin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE ISLOGGEDIN = 1");

if (mysql_num_rows($loggedin) > 0) {
    echo "<table>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loggedin)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
          <td>".$row['FIRST']." ".$row['LAST']."</td>
          <td>".$row['timeloggedin']."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

This code will output every row from table, where `ISLOGGEDIN = 1`.

PS: about data `$row['timeloggedin']`, you dont have it in your query (as seen in `var_dump`), so it will be an empty string.

Comment: Thanks very much, just tested and working! RE PS:Yeah that was one that I'd CTRL+C'd from another part of the script and forgot to update it. Cheers!